# Google cloud ML training time

Tags: google

I am using google cloud ML for training data of 1000 images of size 200kb-300kb and using tensorflow to detect objects

Following are my specs:

**`**CPU: 2 core, 8GB RAM, GPU: 1 NVIDIA TESLA P100**`**

I want to calculate the price but i am unsure how long it will take to train the images by knowing the time i can estimate the price

any help will be greatly appreciated I dont have any source to ask except here

Comment: Apart from your question, you have to specify the size of your images. Also consider to use data augmentation techniques. They are not enough for ML tasks although it depends on your task.

Comment: @Media images are 200Kb-300kb

Comment: @Media updated my question

Comment: 200kb? kilo bit? I meant the dimension not the size.

Comment: @Media 128*128  is the dimension

Comment: If you have this dimensionality, try to use colab. Your task does not take too much time and it is not needed to pay. colab is free and has tesla K80.

Comment: how long it will take with colab any rough idea

Comment: depends on your ml task.

Comment: Ml task is only to train data using tensorflow

Comment: So you have a deep learning task, how many parameters do you have? Is your task classification? what is the architecture? DL model selection is an iterative task but because it is free it is not really important. Maybe less than 5 hours if everything goes right!

Comment: task is about object detection and model using is Faster RCNN with Inception Resnet v2

Comment: Your model is heavy but if you don't find a good model, you can save your model after each 12 hours and resume training from where you left off. You can save your model in your drive account.